# Issue with Twilio.Conversations AndroidSDK Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/twilio/util/TwilioLogger

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, twilio

I have a BindingLibrary generated from twilio-conversations-android-6.0.4.aar

When I call CreateConversationsClient I get Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/twilio/util/TwilioLogger.

Twilio AndroidSDK doesn't contain Twilio.Logger class.